# save in a function onchange (Odoo)

Tags: odoo, onchange, odoo-8

I have a field type char "name" and a function onchange for this field.
I want save the register complete when i modified the field "name"
Something like:

```
@api.onchange('name')
    def _onchange_name(self):
        #Save the register on the BBDD (like press the save button)
```

Comment: your question is note clear: rephrase it, tnx

Comment: I wish that when I make changes to "name" is equal to press the save button

Comment: use the .write method. with the values of the current record

Answer (score 0):

```
register = fields.Float()

@api.depends('name')
def _compute_register(self):
   self.register = something
```

Comment: that is not i want, i want do a "write" everything in the BBDD not only one field, as when you press the button "save"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add it in your def write() method

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    if vals.get('name'):
        #insert code here
```